# server ip gives blank page with no error, ftp, other domain pointing to server works well

Tags: apache-2.4, ip-address, dedicated-server, debian-jessie

Just new user in dedicated server, I installed debian 8 and many packages (Apache2, proftpd, mariadb, bind9, ...). Everything was working well for 2 weeks.

My server IP adress was pointing to debian welcome page in /var/www/html. I took a domain name (murvielinfo.com), and it was working well. I configure an external domain pointing on this server (vidayalma.net), working OK.

After several manipulations, now my IP adress returns a blank page, domain name (murvielinfo.com) also. But the external domain (vidayalma.net) is still working well. Also FTP, phpmyadmin, SSH login ...

I certainly did something ridiculous, but after long time research, I'm going crazy to fix the problem.

If you have any idea, it would be great...

Comment: It is impossible to tell what is wrong in your configuration if we cannot see it.

Comment: Sure, but as you can see in my question, I was a brand new owner of a server I was trying to configure with empirical configurations. Apache is not easy to handle. However, [HBruijn's](https://serverfault.com/users/37681/hbruijn) answer helped me. A little after, I switched to Nginx, and it's much easier for me…

Answer (score 2):

Sending a web request to the ip-address of a server with multiple name based virtual hosts typically returns the **default** VirtualHost.

The default [`VirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) in Apache   is either:

- the first `<VirtualHost addr[:port] >` entry in your `httpd.conf`
- the specific VirtualHost marked as default with `<VirtualHost _default_[:port] >`
- In the case all your VirtualHosts have a separate configuration files that are merged into the effective configuration with [`Include conf.d/*.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) or [`IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#includeoptional) directives, the default is first alphabetically of those configuration files.

`murvielinfo.com` is probably your default VirtualHost and you broke that and therefore a request to `163.172.43.79` also fails.

To debug what is broken, as always, to take a look at your servers log files, especially the Apache error_log.

Comment: Exact, swaping between command lines and Webmin, I had deleted the default configuration. I understood that the host name of the server should also be defined as a **Virtual**Host, the **default** one. I recovered a brand new 000-default.conf, set the domain name and it works as expected.